# ROS Chat Group?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a random question as I have lots of questions to ask, is there any active Chat group for ROS?  I have quite a few questions and really don't want to spam the word (people have already been really helpful)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252237/ros-chat-group?/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technical questions are best asked here, on ROS Answers (after having searched for similar questions and answers). For more general discussion, https://discourse.ros.org may be appropriate. There used to be a ROS Slack organization (essentially a chat room), but it has been phased out in favor of https://discourse.ros.org I believe. Ditto for the mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-17**:
Thank you, I need to get a custom robot up and running pretty quick and have some of it working, just need  help piecing the final parts together

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-17**:
This book might help then: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do (I'm not affiliated in any way)

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-18**:
I think I have that one and 2 others on my Kindle, the issue I have is time (kids) plus I feel I am nearly there.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-13**:
Man I wish there was a chat group, stuck for days and no ones replying :(

**Comment by [w](https://answers.ros.org/users/29217/w/) on 2017-03-14**:
I absolutely agree.
With as many of us involved in this, it shouldn't be too much of a task to get such a chat group going. I love answers as a resource, but whether you get a response is totally random... Time is valuable, for all of us, what can I do to help promote this idea?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-04-21**:
For what it's worth, asking questions here is beneficial to everyone because people having the same problem in the future are more likely to find it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's also a (non-official) chat room on `chat.freenode.net` called `#ros`, for those of you interested in chatting in an IRC channel.

---

Originally posted by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) with karma: 372 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1